# can't get content of the page with file_get_contents

Tags: php

Try to get content of page with `file_get_contents`

Page: http://www.sapporo-keihan.jp/maruyama/outline

```
function pageContent(String $url): \DOMDocument
    {
       $html = cache()->rememberForever($url, function () use ($url) {

           $opts = [
               "http" => [
                   "method" => "GET",
                   "header" => "Accept: text/html\r\n"
               ]
           ];
           $context = stream_context_create($opts);
           $file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

           return $file;

       });
       $parser = new \DOMDocument();
       libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

       $parser->loadHTML($html = mb_convert_encoding($html,'HTML-ENTITIES', 'ASCII, JIS, UTF-8, EUC-JP, SJIS'));

       return $parser;
    }


    $html = pageContent("http://www.sapporo-keihan.jp/maruyama/outline");
    $path = new \DOMXPath($html);
    $catch = $path->query("//body");
    foreach ($catch as $found){
        $site = trim($found->nodeValue);
    }
```

But I can't return the content properly. Instead of the content it's giving me the css of the page. What is it wrong about the function. What's causing this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Have you turned on error reporting to see any errors? Have you checked your logs for errors?

Comment: i use comment  on the `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` but no error returns still  it's giving me the css data  ? @kerbholz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that for this url the server returns css by default. Specify the http `Accept: text/html` header to fix this.

You can do it the following way:

```
$opts = [
  "http" => [
    "method" => "GET",
    "header" => "Accept: text/html\r\n"
  ]
];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```